# Design pattern for locking on regeneration of cached resource

Tags: caching, locking

This is a programming language agnostic question as it speaks to a situation which could occur on any development platform.

1. Lets imagine that you have a resource which is cached in a manner where it will expire based on time passed.
2. That resource will be accessed in a multi-threaded environment.
3. Periodically the resource will expire and we want only **one** thread to regenerate the cache, the other threads should wait and return the resource the first thread acquired.
4. To reduce overhead, we only want to perform a resource lock when the resource has expired allowing lock-free cache reads.

I'm wondering is if there is a common design pattern for handling this sort of situation?

Here is my pseudocode attempt at solving the problem:

```
// check for resource. If it exists return it.
if(inCache()) {
    return getCachedResource();
}

// resource has expired, sychronize users so only 
// one executes the following block at a time
lock {
    // check if a previous request re-cached the resource
    if (inCache()) {
        return getCachedResource();
    }

    // get the resource
    getResource();
    return getCachedResource();
}
```

Is there a better way to solve this problem? Are there additional concerns I may not have considered?

Comment: I don't think you need the inCache() check inside the lock block. Another request couldn't have added to the cache, right? (The block is synchronous)

Comment: The block is synchronous, but once the first request finishes, the second request, which was waiting on the lock, will then execute the code inside that block, causing it to be re-cached yet again. This will always occur if multiple requests come in while the first request is still in-progress re-caching.

Comment: Of course, you're right. Duh. Sorry.